# $5$ points on ellipse

Tags: conic-sections, coordinate-systems, polygons

I want to take five points and locate them on ellipse so that the distance between the point $1$ and point $2$, the point $2$ and point $3$, the point $3$ and point $4$, the point $4$ and point $5$, the point $5$ and point $1$ were equal to each other. I think it will look like a polygon with equal side lengths, but with different angles.
Can you help me to figure out how to find the distance among those points and the coordinates of those points if the minor and major axes are $b$ and $a$ respectively?

Comment: Are you starting with the five points or with the ellipse?  Normally it takes four points to determine an ellipse so the fifth will probably not be on the ellipse going through the first four.  Do you want the distances to be measured in straight lines between the points or around the curve of the ellipse?  Arc lengths of ellipses are usually impossible to calculate analytically, so you would be into numeric approximation.  That is not all bad, just pointing it out.

Comment: Let me know if my interpretation of the given problem is correct: we have an ellipse with equation $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}$ and an equilateral pentagon with known side length inscribed in such ellipse. Can we find the location of the vertices of the pentagon in a explicit way?

Comment: We are starting from an ellipse and I want the distance to be measured in straight lines between the points.

Comment: We do not have the length of the pentagon's sides. We need to determine them.

Comment: It doesn’t look easy, but in case you haven’t found these similar questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2135215/equilateral-polygon-inscribed-within-an-ellipse and https://mathoverflow.net/a/28159/8201

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equilateral polygon inscribed within an ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2135215/equilateral-polygon-inscribed-within-an-ellipse)

Comment: err, wrong _" Normally it takes four points to determine an ellipse so the fifth will probably not be on the ellipse going through the first four"_ it always takes 5 points to uniquely determine a conic in the plane

Comment: It is not unique. Depeding on whether a vertex is on end of major axis or  on end of minor axis solutions  are different.. you can sketch it. (You want to find the set of all equilateral pentagons inscribed in a given  ellipse, right? )

Answer (score 1):

In a fixed ellipse there are infinite inscribed equilateral pentagons, with different side lengths. You may start from a point $P$ on the ellipse and define, for any sufficiently small $\ell>0$, $f_{\ell}(P)$ as the point $Q$ of the ellipse such that $PQ=\ell$ and $P$ occurs "shortly before" $Q$ when travelling the ellipse counter-clockise. Let $R=(f_\ell\circ f_\ell\circ f_\ell\circ f_\ell\circ f_\ell)(P)$. For small values of $\ell$, $R$ occurs "shortly after" $P$, but for large values of $\ell$ the point $R$ occurs "shortly before" $P$. By continuity, for some value of $\ell$ (which depends on the location of $P$) we have $R\equiv P$, leading to an inscribed equilateral pentagon. But such function ($P\mapsto \ell_{\text{crit}}$) is not constant on the ellipse: in general we have infinite inscribed equilateral pentagons, with slightly (*very* slightly, if the eccentricity is small) different side lengths.

Hence a range of possible side lengths, not a single side length:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have not thought about the fact that I can draw infinitely many pentagons in an ellipse. However, is it possible to find the length of the polygon's side if one of its points is located on the (0,b), where b is the length of the small axis? If yes could you show me, please?

Comment: Where have you done this scheme? Is it possible to find the equation of the ellipse and points in it?

Comment: @АсмирАбдимажитов: if a vertex of the pentagon is also a vertex of the ellipse the problem is much simpler due to symmetry, but also pretty different from the stated one. The diagram above has been drawn through Geogebra. A sort of Poncelet's porism holds, but the grey curve is not really an ellipse.

Comment: I think it could be an ellipse since. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Equation of the ellipse :
$$\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^2=1$$
with given values $a,b$.

They are many solutions, depending where we put the first point on the ellipse.

If you want only one solution, one of the simplest is obtained in putting the first point A on $(x=a,y=0)$.

See Figure below. With AB=BC=CD=DE=EA=$L$, at beginning $L$ is unknown. To find it, the equations are :

Point A$(x_1,y_1)$ : 
$$y_1=\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2} \quad;\quad y_1^2+(a-x_1)^2=L^2$$
$$x_1=a\frac{a^2-\sqrt{b^4+(a^2-b^2)L^2}}{a^2-b^2} \tag 1$$
$$y_1=b\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{a^2-\sqrt{b^4+(a^2-b^2)L^2}}{a^2-b^2}\right)^2} \tag 2$$
Point B$(x_2,y_2)$ :
$$y_2=\frac{L}{2} \tag 3$$
$$x_2=a\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{L}{2b}\right)^2} \tag 4$$
Condition to have BC=$L$ : $\quad (x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2=L^2$
$$\left(a\frac{a^2-\sqrt{b^4+(a^2-b^2)L^2}}{a^2-b^2}-a\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{L}{2b}\right)^2}\right)^2+ +\left(b\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{a^2-\sqrt{b^4+(a^2-b^2)L^2}}{a^2-b^2}\right)^2}-a\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{L}{2b}\right)^2}\right)^2=L^2$$
this equation contains only the unknown $L$.

It can be simplified by normalization, with $x=\frac{L}{a}$ , $\beta=\frac{b}{a}$. This leads to an equation with parameter $\beta$ and unknown $x$. But the benefit is not large because transforming the equation with radicals leads to a polynomial equation of degree higher than 5.

Thus, there is no closed form for the unknown $L$. Nevertheless, one can easily solve it for $L$ with numerical calculus. Then the coordinates of the points are computed with Eqs.$(2-4)$. An example is shown on the figure below.

[image]

Comment: That is so amazing! Thank you very much! It is thorough and understandable! Could you share the name of the program you used to draw the picture above, please?

Comment: For numerical calculus : Mathcad. For curve drawing : Sine-qua-non. For finishing touch : ms-paint.

Comment: In this [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2135215/equilateral-polygon-inscribed-within-an-ellipse), they did manage to end up with equations solvable in radicals.