# Solvable or not? If yes how?

Tags: systems-of-equations, radicals

$$-8x^2 +25wx=9 (\sqrt {25-w^2}) (5-\sqrt {25-x^2})$$; 
$$8w^2-8y^2+25x(y-x)=9(\sqrt{25-x^2})(\sqrt{25-w^2}-\sqrt{25-y^2})$$; 
$$25y(z-x)+8x^2-8z^2=9(\sqrt{25-x^2}-\sqrt{25-z^2})$$; $$16y^2+9w^2-9z^2-50zy=18(\sqrt{(25-z^2)(25-y^2)}-5\sqrt{25-w^2} )$$.

Is this system of equations solvable or not?

Comment: please edit your question and provide more info

Comment: what is the meaning of these parenthesis $$[..]$$?

Comment: perhaps its just to show the terms are separate

Comment: It is a 4 equations sytem with 4 unknown variables. So I'd focus on checking that there is no linear dependency between the variables

You can define x'=sqrt(25-x^2), and do the same for the other variables, and try to solve that

Comment: What is the use for the answer? Looks solvable, but I imagine it will take very long to answer.

Comment: I need this equation to be able to find the distance between the successful points of an equaliteral pentagon located on the ellipse whose minor axis's length is 3 and major axis's lenght is 5.

Comment: The OP means this is connected to his [other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2702127/5-points-on-ellipse).